# Is this a correct proof of the inverse function theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This question concerns the proof of the inverse function theorem found in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (3rd ed.). I have found an alternate proof of one part of the theorem but I am unsure of its validity. For the sake of clarity, let me recall the beginning of the argument:

$f:E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuously differentiable function such that its differential $Df_a$ is invertible for some $a \in E$.
For any $ y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ a function $\phi_y: E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by:

$$\phi_y(x)=x+A^{-1}(y-f(x))$$

where $A$ is the matrix of the differential of $f$ at $a$. Points $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ are fixed points of $\phi_y$. It is proved that there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ where $\phi_y$ is a contraction. This implies $f$ is injective in $U$ (because a contraction has at most one fixed point), so $f$ is a bijection from $U$ to $f(U)$.

The next part of the proof is showing that $V=f(U)$ is open. I believe I have found a proof of this that is (somewhat) simpler than Rudin's. However, I have some doubts about its validity since I could not find a similar argument on the internet or other books (Spivak and Munkres are the ones I have at hand, but they do not use the contraction principle). Here is my argument:

**Proof that $V$ is open :**

We actually prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on all of $V$, so $f$ restricted to $U$ is a homeomorphism. This implies V is open since $V=[f^{-1}]^{-1}(U)$ and $U$ is open (in $\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $z$ be any point of $V$. Since $f$ is a bijection from $U$ to $V$, the function $f^{-1}$ is well-defined on $V$. By the definition of $\phi_y$ we have:

$$\phi_y(f^{-1}(z))=f^{-1}(z)+A^{-1}(y-z)$$

which immediately gives:

$$f^{-1}(z)=\phi_y(f^{-1}(z))+A^{-1}(z-y)$$

Thus we have for any $w \in V$:

$$\begin{align}
|f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(w)|& =|\phi_y(f^{-1}(z))-\phi_y(f^{-1}(w))+A^{-1}(z-y)-A^{-1}(w-y)| \\
& \leq |\phi_y(f^{-1}(z))-\phi_y(f^{-1}(w))|+|A^{-1}(z-w)| \\
& \leq k \; |f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(w)|+|A^{-1}(z-w)|
\end{align}
$$

where the last inequality follows since $\phi_y$ is a contraction on $U$ (Rudin uses $k=1/2$). But $k \lt 1$ so we can regroup the terms and divide by $1-k$:

$$
|f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(w)| \leq \frac{1}{1-k}|A^{-1}(z-w)|
\leq \frac{M}{k-1} |z-w| 
$$

where the second inequality holds for some $M\gt0$ since $A^{-1}$ is linear. This implies $|f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(w)|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $|z-w|\lt \epsilon(k-1)/M$ so $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $z$.

**End of proof**

**Attempt at a resolution:**

One thing that I think might be a problem is the following: if I consider $U$ and $V$ as metric spaces with metric induced by their inclusion in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then continuity of $f^{-1}$ means that the inverse image of any set that is open *in* $U$ is a set that is open *in* $V$. This does not show it is open in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Actually, in this regard the fact that $V$ is open in $V$ is a triviality.

**Remarks**

1. One reason why I feel the proof might be wrong is that it doesn't actually use the Banach fixed point theorem while Rudin's proof relies on it in a rather critical way.
2. This is my first question on math.stackexchange so any comments or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Yes, you seem to be implicitly assuming this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain 

Also, note that in one section this very problem is mentioned:

 "Furthermore, the theorem says that if two subsets U and V of Rn are homeomorphic, and U is open, then V must be open as well. (Note that V is open as a subset of Rn, and not just in the subspace topology. Openness of V in the subspace topology is automatic. )"

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did : I proved $f$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ to $V$ and deduced $V$ is open (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) since $U$ is... The proof is correct but using invariance of domain is way too involved for this... Thanks a lot for the link, it clears up everything.